# How to filter several DateFields with the same list_filter

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filters

I am trying to make a custom list_filter to input one date, and then, the app use this date to filter by several fields (not only one).
I have tried [DateRangeFilter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-daterange-filter) lib, but this is to filter by one field between two input dates.

What I need is to filter by several fields (date1, date2, date3...) with only one input date:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date1__gte=InputFilterDate, date2__gte=InputFilterDate,...)
```

All the other custom filters I've seen you have to set a list of possible values, but i don't have possible values, I need a calendar or something similar to input a single date.

Do you know any library similar to DateRangeFilter, or a magic Django API trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the change_list in your templates folder `admin/<app_label>/<object_name>/change_list.html`

And then try to edit the filter block. You should know that Django change_list filtering is based on request query string, you can create a form with GET method who contains inputs with specific name to be able to filter. I added in the code above a jquery script that generate inputs based on fields names array, your code should be like this one:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block filters %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <form action="" method="get" id='date_filter_form'>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_picker">
    </form>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            var fields = ['date1__gte', 'date2__gte'];
            $(document).ready(function($) {
                $("#date_filter_form").submit(function(){
                    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                        $('#date_picker').clone().attr(
                            'name', fields[i]).appendTo($(this));
                    };
                    return true;
                });
            });
        })(django.jQuery);
    </script>
{% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

You can integrate any custom jquery datepicker widget you like, just import js and css and add initialization in the ready function.

Take a look on the change_list.html [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html) to add your css files with the right block name, and don't forget to call `{{ block.super }}` to include admin's change list code else you will override it.